# How to prioritize the linq query which filter should be search first?

Tags: c#, linq

I am doing the payment gateway, However, one merchant can have 1 million records. So in order to allow the merchant to have speed search, in my DB I index merchant id column. So in my c# code, I wish my Linq I wish the query to search the merchant id first. So the query can go into the next search filter to improve the performance. It is any way to allow LINQ to search merchant id first?

```
IQueryable<WithdrawalRecord> withdrawalList = entities.WithdrawalRecord
                               .Where(x => x.MerchantId == merchantId && x.Currency = "USD");
```

Comment: If you created the right indexes, your DBMS should be able to use statistics to determine the best way to execute this query, without having to 'hint' anything

Answer (score -1):

```
entities.WithdrawalRecord.Where(x => x.MerchantId == merchantId).Where(x => x.Currency = "USD");
```

You can stack `Where` calls since it returns an `IQueryable<WithdrawalRecord>`, doing it in this way will apply the filtering on `merchantId` prior to applying the filtering on currency.